# Liquibase hibernate connection warning in Spring 5 project

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am using liquibase in Spring 5 project with Maven. I have annotation based connection, and liquibase properties file. However when I interact with liquibase via maven goals I get the following warning: **HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections**

Here is the JPA configuration class:

```
package dev.cvetan.bezglavi.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "dev.cvetan.bezglavi.repository")
public class JPAConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("dev.cvetan.bezglavi.entity");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);
        em.setJpaProperties(aditionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname");
        dataSource.setUsername("dbuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("dbpass");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    public Properties aditionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Here is the liquibase properties:

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
username=dbuser
password=dbuser
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:dev.cvetan.bezglavi.entity?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

and pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dev.cvetan</groupId>
    <artifactId>bezglavi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>14</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jpa dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- web dependencies - needed for spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- needed for rest api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <logging>info</logging>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.10.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>3.10.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello, have you fixed the warning? I have the same issue occurring.